# SublimeText 3 "Failed to start Server"

Tags: html, popup, sublimetext3

When editing `html` files in SublimeText3 I frequently get a messagebox reading `Failed to start Server`. It also creates a console entry `error: Failed to start server`.

I did not install any packages that should interact with `html` files that I know of. The files are not associated with a sublime project.

Where does this message come from?

It's really distracting (more so then the "please buy me" popups).

Answer (score 1):

Did you then install any JS packages?

https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_sublime/blob/master/tern.py

This plugin has the error text failed to start server. 
Could also be sublime tries to connect to their server but failed.